# How to get past information while converting speech to text in android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-voice

As i am developing an android app and wants to convert speech into text, i am using built-in Google speech input activity to convert voice into text. I need past information but it continuously get cleared i got only current response. How need to handle same as google voice keyboard. As i talk it included to current String instep of clear.

**MainActivity .java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  {
     private EditText txtSpeechInput;
     private ImageButton btnSpeak;
     private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      txtSpeechInput =  findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
      btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });
   private void promptSpeechInput()
      {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 20000000);

  try
    {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT:
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
            {

              final ArrayList<String> result= data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by past information? What I understand from your question, you want to get previously set string as well?

Comment: yes, exactly @AbdulWaheed

Comment: you want to save only previous string or all string consecutively?

Comment: want all string consecutively. As he started speaking previous string should not clear

Comment: hmmm ok I am updating my answer.

Comment: I tried it. But not working, it always getting cleared

Comment: In that case shared the code you tried...tell me one more thing you want to save this even the activity is destroyed? I mean you are moving to difference activitis and coming back and the list empty? is this the case you are facing?

Comment: if you want to hold data entire app life you can make this list variable as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to save one previously detected String, for this to achieve, you need to make a global String variable and store the value in that variable from results list.(Save the same String as you are setting on text view). But if you want to save all the strings, you need to make global **String Arraylist** and add all those string in that array list. Below is the code for that.

```
private EditText txtSpeechInput;
private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
private List<String> previousStringList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    previousStringList = new ArrayList<>();

    txtSpeechInput = findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });
}

private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 20000000);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                final ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);


                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                if (result.get(0) != null) {
                    previousStringList.add(result.get(0));
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope that helps you.If you don't understand anything feel free to ask. If you don't want to save same String twice(already saved string), just replace below conditional line of code..

```
if (result.get(0) != null && !previousStringList.contains(result.get(0))) {
    previousStringList.add(result.get(0));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The words get stored in Arraylists.

You can see an example of the implementation here, it works fine. The app stores the words, and then also performs the action requested.

https://github.com/saumyabahu/Travel-Safe/blob/master/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
private Intent intentRecognizer;
private EditText txtSpeechInput;

private ImageButton btnSpeak;
```

//this is the string in which words get stored and past strings with left to right cursor.
String previous = " ";

//  ArrayList result = null;

```
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    // ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );


    txtSpeechInput = findViewById( R.id.ed );


    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.iButton );



    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            promptSpeechInput();


        }
    } );

}

private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent( RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH );
    intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM );
    intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault() );
    intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString( R.string.speech_prompt ) );

    intent.putExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 20000000 );



    try {
        startActivityForResult( intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT );
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),
                getString( R.string.speech_not_supported ),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, data );

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                final ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra( RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS );
```

//this is the real problem.
txtSpeechInput.setText( previous + " " + result.get( 0 )  );

```
                previous = txtSpeechInput.getText().toString();

                txtSpeechInput.setText( previous );




            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

}